# How to combine many OR statements in an if statement

Tags: c#

Say this:

```
if (stars == 2 || stars ==6 || stars ==10)
{
    do something
}
```

is there's a way to combined them together as if:

```
if (stars == {2, 4, 6}) <--- MATLAB style
{
       do something
}
```

Comment: if ((new[] { 2, 6, 10 }).Contains(stars)) { …

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you could write an extension like this:

```
public static class GenericExtensions
{
    public static bool In<T>(this T @this, params T[] listOfItems)
    {
        if (null == listOfItems) return false;
        return listOfItems.Contains(@this);
    }
}
```

and then use it like:

`if (2.In(1,2,3,4))`

Comment: Everything is better with extension methods :-)

Comment: and maybe, check my nuget package for this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronSphere.Extensions/ there are many extensions, like this one :) - and I will add some more in future.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger could you please explain more? Mine return Int.System32 does not contain a definition for In. Sorry for the clumsy question, first time using extension.

Comment: I updated my answere. You need to add extension-methods into a static class, then it should work. (There are no clumsy questions, just clumsy answeres ;) )

Comment: You can reduce the overhead of this method significantly by defining additional overloads with a finite number of parameters instead of using params and then using the simple || conditional.

Comment: @AndrewHanlon so you would write thousands of overloads for this function? Because, I really don't know how many parameters I will need maximum with `In<T>(params)` during my development-process. (And, I'm not interrested in knowing that). For me, it's mostly about "the easy way" - I don't want to spend hours for copy-pasting my methods only because I now need 37 parameters instead of just 34.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger I think you've misinterpreted my comment - I was only implying that if you add a few concrete overloads (to a reasonable count like 5 params) then the vast majority of cases will be covered with a highly performant function. You could even add the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` attribute which would inline the condition in most cases. Cheers.

Comment: @AndrewHanlon Ahh okay. Now I understand. Yes this could be more performant. Sry, missed the "additional" in your comment. Thx for the `MethodImpl`-thing. I'm going to check, how it works and what it does :)

Answer (score 4):

Not as part of the language "MATLAB style" but you can use an array and [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var items = new []{2,4,6};
if(items.IndexOf(stars) > -1)
{
  // do something
}
```

or similar with [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var items = new List<int>{2,4,6};
if(items.Contains(stars))
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: In the end it's a matter of personal taste, but I prefer the Contains version. It seems cleaner and more self-explanatory to me.

Comment: @Gertsen me too, but its a bit more heavyweight, as requires a List.

Comment: True, but it's easily readable, and that's important too. Anyone can make code a computer can read. Making code that humans can easily read is much harder.